# How To Get A Part Of String?

Tags: android, string

I need to get a link url from string to create button in my app.

```
String html="<p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
<p>This is a string</p>
<a href="http://mylink.com/pp">This is my default link</a>
<p>I want to get just my default link</p>
<a href="http://mylink.com/kk">This is my 2nd default link</a>
<p>bla bla bla</p>";
```

I tried to split but didn't success because the solution isn't splitting. I want to get http://mylink.com/kk and http://mylink.com/pp links.

Comment: What did you try to split on? What did you get as a result? You could *try* a regular expression or something similar but this is Almost Always A Bad Idea.

Comment: Yes i know its bad idea but as in rules, I should write my tries. Part of the act

(I didnt try. I taught)

Answer (score 1):

startIndex = indexOf("http://");

endIndex = indexOf("\"",startIndex)

link = substring(startIndex, endIndex-1)

Comment: then you can just update your startIndex as endIndex i.e. 
original answer. Below that add this line: startIndex = endIndex. Run your code in infinte loop but break it as soon as endIndex == -1